# update list of dict by key from another list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dicts:

```
a = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'test'}]
```

I need to update the dicts in `a` with the key `'name'` from the dicts of `b` by key `'id'`. Result which I expected:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'test'}]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Aren't you just copying `b` into `a`? Also python dicitonaries are unordered.

Comment: How have you tried to do it? @EricJin `b` has one more dict that gets filtered out... Well I would transform `a` to a set of the ids and then filter those from `b`...

Comment: I think in the first code block with `b=` you have unbalanced brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a `filter` process, get a list of filter scope first and do the filter

```
a = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test'}, {
    'id': 3, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'test'}]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] in [i['id'] for i in a], b)))
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'test'}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should first create an "index" of the dictionaries in list `b`, then you can update list `a` using a list comprehension:

```
ib = { d["id"]:d for d in b }
a  = [ {**d,**ib.get(d["id"],{})} for d in a ]
```

Comment: Why not just `[ib.get(d["id"], {}) for d in a]`?

Comment: I'm assuming that the dictionaries in `a` could have other keys that you wouldn't want to lose.  If not then yes that would suffice but it should be written as `[ib.get(d["id"], d) for d in a]` in case a dictionary in `b` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Converting `a` to a set of ids for membership lookups could be a solution as well:

```
ids = {x["id"] for x in a}

result = [x for x in b if x["id"] in ids]

print(result)
# [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'test'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'test'}]
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same solution, but Alain T. raises a valid point that this could be a problem in case the dicts in `a` have more keys. Of course, according to the example that seems like a fine solution

Comment: @Tomerikoo I definitely agree. Its unclear if this is good enough for the OP's use case. Its not really clear in the question. I posted it anyways since it seems to be fine for what the OP is after, judging by the correct answer.